# Setting a placeholder value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the placeholder using the tasks array but the page turns blank when i refresh the page, the correct values are shown before refreshing but the page turns blank when refreshed.

```
<input type="text" id="edit" placeholder={tasks.find(task => task.id === parseInt(selectedTask)).value}  ref={editTaskRef} onBlur={() => editTask()}/>
```

I tried making it a function and that loads the page but doesnt set any values in the placeholder

```
<input type="text" id="edit" placeholder={() => tasks.find(task => task.id === parseInt(selectedTask)).value}  ref={editTaskRef} onBlur={() => editTask()}/>
```

full code of the page

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TodoListItem />
    </div>
  )
}

const TodoListItem = () => {
  //for inputs
  const inputTaskRef = useRef()
  const editTaskRef = useRef()

  //for task management
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

  //for sidebar
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState("") 
  const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = useState("")

  //shows the sidebar
  const TodoItemDetails = () => {
    setToggle(false)
    setGrid("grid grid-cols-2")
  }

  //form handling
  const onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let value = inputTaskRef.current.value

    if(value !== ""){
      let task = {
        id: index,
        task: <Task value={value} key={index} id={index} />,
        value: value
      }

      setIndex((index) => index+1)
      setTasks((oldTasks) => [ ...oldTasks, task ])

      inputTaskRef.current.value = ""
    }
  }

  //closes the sidebar
  const closeSideBar = () => {
    setToggle(true)
    setGrid("")
    editTaskRef.current.value = ""
  }

  //task hook
  const Task = (props) => {
    return(
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => {
          TodoItemDetails()
          setSelectedTask(props.id)
          editTaskRef.current.value = ""
        }} className="bg-white w-full hover:bg-gray-200 p-4 my-1 rounded shadow-sm text-left">{props.value}</button>
       </li>
    )
  }

  //for editing a task
  const editTask = () => {
    let value = editTaskRef.current.value

    if(value !== ""){
      let editedTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === parseInt(selectedTask))
      tasks[editedTaskIndex].task = <Task value={value} key={index} id={selectedTask} />
      tasks[editedTaskIndex].value = value

      editTaskRef.current.value = ''
    }
  }
  
  //for deleting a task
  const deleteTask = () => {
    let deletedTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === parseInt(selectedTask))
    tasks.splice(deletedTaskIndex, 1)

    editTaskRef.current.value = ''

    closeSideBar()
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100 items-center justify-center min-h-screen min-w-screen p-4">
        <div className={grid}>

          <div>  
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className="bg-white rounded py-4 px-2 my-4 h-16 shadow-sm">
              <input className="w-[85%] sm:w-[87%] md:w-[90%] lg:w-[95%] h-full float-left focus:outline-none placeholder-blue-500 ml-2 py-1 focus:placeholder-black" type="text" id="task" placeholder="Add a task" ref={inputTaskRef} onFocus={() => closeSideBar()}/>
              <button type="submit" className="text-blue-500 float-right text-2xl -translate-y-0.5 -translate-x-1">+</button>
            </form>
            <ul>{tasks.map(task => task.task)}</ul>
          </div>

          <div hidden={toggle} className={"bg-white rounded py-2.5 px-2 ml-5 my-4 h-72 shadow-sm "+grid}>
            <input className="col-start-1 col-end-3 w-100 h-12 float-left focus:outline-none placeholder-blue-500 focus:placeholder-black ml-2 " type="text" id="edit" placeholder={tasks.find(task => task.id === parseInt(selectedTask)).value}  ref={editTaskRef} onBlur={() => editTask()}/>
            <button className="col-start-1 col-end-2 text-blue-500 h-[400px] text-2xl mr-14" onClick={() => deleteTask()}>delete</button>
            <button className="col-start-2 col-end-3 text-blue-500 h-[400px] text-2xl ml-14" onClick={() => closeSideBar()}>x</button>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first enter the page, `selectedTask` are just `""` (empty string) from the initial state, that why it is show blank.

Comment: yupp i used console to check the values and found out the issue...thank you for the response !!

Answer (score 0):

When TodoListItem is first mounted the tasks and selectedTask are empty array([]) and empty string('') respectively. In case you want to prevent this data from resetting, you should store there value in localStorage using :

```
localStoarge.setItem('selectedtask', selectedTask); 
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
```

also make sure to set there initial value:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = 
useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || []);

const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = 
useState(localStorage.getItem('selectedtask') || "")
```